# function prototype return 2D array in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, function-prototypes

I am not very good at C and I am really confused about double array. Below is an outline of a code I have a question about. Main function calls CreateRandConn function and passes it a 2D array filled with 0 as an argument. CreateRandConn function takes a 2D array as a parameter, changes some of the value in 2DArray from 0 to 1 and returns the changed 2DArray back to main. I want to indicate in the function prototype the return type of CreateRandConn function is a 2D array. How do I indicate that? I don't really understand the syntax. Is what I wrote wrong? Is the way I am passing the 2DArray as a parameter in the function header incorrect? If so, how I do write it? I still get confused about the relationship between pointers and double arrays. Can someone explain it with the below code outline? Hopefully someone knows what my question is...

```
//Function prototype
int ** CreateRandConn(char * RandRoom[7], int my2DArray[7][7], char * room_dir);

//Function
int ** CreateRandConn(char * RandRoom[7], int my2DArray[7][7], char * room_dir)
{
   ...
   return my2DArray;
}

int main()
{
   int 2DArray[7][7] = {0}; 
   2DArray = CreateRandConn(RandRoomArray, my2DArray[7][7], room_dir);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try this: `CreateRandomConn(RandRoomArray, my2DArray, room_dir);`

Answer (score 5):

> I don't really understand the syntax.

Ok, so let's recap the basics:

1. One cannot assign to an array variable.
2. If an array gets passed to a function it "*decays*" to a pointer to its 1st element.
3. A multidimensional array is just an array of arrays. So a 2D-array is a 1D-array of 1D-arrays, a 3D-array is a 1D-array of 2D-arrays, a 4D-array is a 1D-array of 3D-arrays, and so on ...
4. A pointer `p` to an array of `N` elements of type `T` is to be defined as: `T (*p)[N]`

Now for you example:

You have

```
int 2DArray[7][7] = ...;
```

for the sake of clarity of the following explanations I change this to be

```
int a[5][7] = ...;
```

So this then is passed to a function. Where the following happens/applies:

- Following 1. above, it is not possible to pass an array, as if it were possible one would assign it to the variable inside the function, as arrays cannot be assigned, one cannot pass an array.
- Following 2. above, the function would need to define the related variable as "*a pointer to the arrays 1st element*".
- Following 3. above, the `a`'s 1st element is an `int [7]`
- Following 4. above, a pointer to an `int[7]` will be defined as: `int(*)[7]`.

So the function's relevant variable would look like:

```
... func(int (*pa)[7])
```

`pa` points to the 1st element of `a`. As a side note: From this pointer `a` the function *cannot* derive how many elements `a` actually "provides", will say: how many valid element after the one `a` points to will follow, so this needs to be passed to the function as well:

```
... func(int (*pa)[7], size_t rows)
```

From the steps so far we learned, that an array is not passed, but just a *pointer* to it's 1st element <sup>*1</sup> is passed, is *copied* into the function's local variable (`pa` here).

From this directly follows that an array cannot be passed back as the function's return value, but just a pointer to an array's element (typically the 1st)

Looking at how a pointer to an array is defined: `T (*p)[N]` we know need to derive how a function returning a pointer to an array would look. The function's defalcation somewhat needs to become the `p` above. So taking `T` as `int` and `N` as 7 we then get:

```
int (*func(int (*pa)[7], size_t rows))[7];
```

The trivial implementation and usage then would be:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for size_t */

#define ROWS (5)
#define COLS (7)

int (*func(int (*pa)[COLS], size_t rows))[COLS];

int (*func(int (*pa)[COLS], size_t rows))[COLS]
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < COLS; ++j)  
    {
      pa[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }

  return pa;
}

int main(void)
{
  int a[ROWS][COLS];

  int (*pa)[COLS] = func(a, ROWS);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

<sup>*1
 (which sloppy, but wrongly spoken often is referred to as "*a pointer to an array is passed*", which **in general it is not**, but just here, as it's a 2D-array, will say the array's elements are arrays themselves).</sup>

---

If you understood the above, then just for completeness following a less strange looking (but also probably less educational ;-)) version of the above function declaration. It may be declared by using a `typedef` construct hiding away the somehow complicated declaration of the array-pointers as parameter and return type.

This

```
typedef int (*PA)[COLS];
```

defines a type pointing a an array of `COLS` of `int`s.

So using `PA` we can instead of

```
int (*func(int (*pa)[COLS], size_t rows))[COLS];
```

write

```
PA func(PA pa, size_t rows))[COLS];
```

This version is identical to the above.

And yes it looks simpler, but brings along the fact, that pointers `pa` and the function's return value) are not identifiable as being pointers by just looking at their definition. Such constructs are considered "bad practice" by many fellow programmers.

Comment: This should get marked for the community wiki so there is a handy reference to the thorough answer for a very frequently asked question. Well done.

Comment: Thanks alk! This was very helpful in understanding multidimensional arrays!

Comment: Actually you can assign an array. You just can't assign it TO an array ( but you can assign it to a pointer). E.g. this works fine: `int a[5][7] = {0}; int (*pa)[7] = a;`

Comment: @SiggiSv: "Cannot assign ***to*** ...." - That is  what I want to express. Fixed and thank you. Still no native speaker ... :}